# Proof of Young's convolutions inequality for a general measure on $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Is Young's inequality true for an arbitrary measure on $\mathbb R^d$?   If so, where can I find a proof of it?  In particular, where can I find the proof of the discrete version (i.e the version for $\ell^p$ spaces) of this inequality?

Here is the statement of the inequality (from Wikipedia):

Suppose $f$ is in $L^p(\mathbb R^d)$ and $g$ is in $L^q(\mathbb R^d)$ and 
$$ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{r} + 1$$

with $1\leq p, q, r\leq \infty$

then 
$$ || f * g || _r \leq ||f||_p ||g||_q.$$

Comment: It strikes me as unlikely that there is a generalization to
arbitrary measures. Lebesgue measure is translation invariant
and the definition of convolution implicitly uses translation.

Comment: The analogous result holds for locally compact groups with unimodular Haar measure. See for example section 20 in chapter 5 of Hewitt and Ross: http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC&lpg=PP1&dq=hewitt%20ross&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false In particular this gives a version for the sequence spaces indexed by Z.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that if your measure is not translation-invariant, the convolution product is not commutative.

This allows for a simple counterexample with $r=q=\infty$, $p=1$,
$d\mu(x)={\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(x) dx$.

Define $f*g(x)= \int f(x-s)g(s)d\mu(s) \ (\neq g*f(x))$.

Take $g\equiv 1, \ f={\bf 1}_{[1,2]}$.
This gives $||f||_1=0$, but the spreading in the convolution makes the left term non zero.

$\max_x \ \ \int_0^1 {\bf 1}_{[1,2]}(x-s)ds =1$.

Just add $\varepsilon e^{-|x|}dx$ to $d\mu$ to get a counterexample with a measure of full support. I think that the reasonable setting for a Young inequality is the case of a translation invariant measure on a locally compact group. Jonas Mayer gave a reference (Hewitt and Ross) for that case in the comments.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to find a counterexample for any measure that is not translation invariant

Comment: @Yang. The Young inequality holds for the Dirac measure. It is just the not very interesting bound $|f(0)g(0)|\leq |f(0)||g(0)|$. So maybe there are counterexamples for any non-atomic measure of full support that is not translation invariant. We can also ask when it holds if we allow a multiplicative constant in the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add comments - so this is to be regarded as such:

In [SHARPNESS IN YOUNG'S INEQUALITY
FOR CONVOLUTION by JOHN J. F. FOURNIER](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-72/issue-2/Sharpness-in-Youngs-inequality-for-convolution/pjm/1102811121.full)
the author proves that, under certain conditions on the underlying locally compact unimodular group, the Young inequality can be improved with a constant $C<1$ in front of the RHS of the standard inequality